# Should I avoid a Singleton in this case?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've been thinking about using a singleton on my data class in my current app. I've also been thinking of reasons not to use the pattern and currently I am stuck in the middle.

The reason I am for the singleton in this case is due to accessibility to methods and properties easily that I need to use more than once throughout the app. I could use the appDelegate for this but that muddles up the area of concern as these methods / variables have nothing to do with the app state - more to do with user input. The data will be persisted with eventually with NSUserDefaults - which is a singleton already.

The reason I am against it is because its another singleton to an app that already bass one (The appDelegate)

My question:

Would using another Singleton to access the data model be the correct way / acceptable way of doing it - or should I look at another approach?

I personally think there would be nothing wrong with a singleton as a data model - using the app delegate to instantiate it when the app starts and then access its various methods / properties when I need them throughout the app. This would be the only other singleton in the app (Maybe another one for user management - e.g.; logging in / out / profile / credentials, etc? )

Any thoughts?

Thanks all!

Comment: From my point of view it would be fine for creating singleton - I would prefer to have own singleton rather than messing in AppDelegate

Comment: I'm trying to leave the AppDelegate alone as much as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem having multiple singleton classes within ios, in fact in many of my projects most of the classes are singletons. Normally I have the data access logic and control within a singleton and then actual object classes as instances.

As you have already identified you really do not want to be putting something into AppDelegate that does not apply to the whole app.

From my point of view do not instanciate the class from AppDelegate, simply have the class instanciate itself on first access.

Whenever I am explaining singleton Objective-C to people I always direct them to this site, it may be worth a view for you:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

It explains only what you need in a really easy to understand way. The bit that does the 'self-instanciating' is this bit:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this very useful post. Heading over to the link now. I guess its a singleton I will go for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use singleton in these case. Don't use delegate to hold values for your app. You may use same singleton for user management also.

**Note :** Don't use globals unless you need to do so. Singletons and top-level data should be used only when the data they contain truly belongs at the top level.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I won't be using any global variables. By their nature they can be changed at anytime by anything throughout the app - something I don't like.

Comment: Do you know one thing? Singleton value is always in memory until app get kill like globals? that's why I mention like this. I didn't mean, you have used that.

Comment: Oh okay now it makes sense. Instead of accessing a property - I could just access a method from the singleton class to set the property to a value I need. This way - that value is not kept in a global state?